# Snowflake date conversion from varchar

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-conversion

I have a field in my table that is a varchar datatype. I need to convert it to a date with YYYYMMDD format.

I am trying the date, to_date, try_to_date, to_timestamp functions.

```
SELECT
    START_DATE AS START_DATE_ORIG,
    TRY_TO_DATE(START_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') AS START_DATE
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

They either error with this.

`SQL Error [100097] [22007]: Can't parse '12/1/2018 12:00:00 AM' as date with format 'YYYYMMDD'`

Or show me this result with null values.

[image]

Comment: This is a common misconception.  The format defined in the function is not for the output format, but rather the input format of the string you are attempting to transform to a date.  Dates in Snowflake are all stored the same and display is a session or account parameter.  `to_varchar` would allow you to specify an output format of the date, but the output is a string, not a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to convert your varchar to date format to parse properly the date value, then you can output it again to varchar, but setting the output format for date. Try this:

```
SELECT
    START_DATE AS START_DATE_ORIG,
    to_varchar(TO_DATE(START_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'), 'YYYYMMDD') AS START_DATE
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

I could mixed up `DD` and `MM`, make sure it is correct for your local preferences.